# start method in a fragment from a different class

Tags: android, firebase, android-maps

Am trying to execute a method onclicklistener from a different class in a fragment. Am having this error. I am new to programming, would anyone be kind enough to help me filter this problem.

This is the method on BottomSheetMotoristFragment.java

```
bRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();


            if (!Common.isDriverFound)
                mainAct.requestPickUpHere(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

            else
                Common.sendRequestToDriver(Common.driverId,mFcmService,mainAct.getBaseContext(),Common.mLastLocation);



        }
    });
```

This is the method i would like to call from MainActivity.java

```
public void requestPickUpHere(String uid) {

    DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.pickup_request_tbl);
    GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
    mGeoFire.setLocation(uid,new GeoLocation(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    if (mUserMarker.isVisible())
        mUserMarker.remove();


    //Add new marker

   mUserMarker =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .title("Pickup Here")
           .snippet("")
           .position(new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

    mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();

    bRequest.setText("Getting your driver......");

    findDriver();



}
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.isVisible()' on a null object reference
    at hushtagstudios.com.towme.MainActivity.requestPickUpHere(MainActivity.java:888)
    at hushtagstudios.com.towme.BottomSheetMotoristFragment$1.onClick(BottomSheetMotoristFragment.java:91)
```

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: i just edited,just check it

Comment: my one cent: you never call the constructor of any activity.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have provided, there is one suspect:

```
public void requestPickUpHere(String uid) {

    DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.pickup_request_tbl);
    GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
    mGeoFire.setLocation(uid,new GeoLocation(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    // IT IS NOT CLEAR WHERE YOU GET mUserMarker (probably it is a field of a class)
    // BUT LOOKS LIKE AT THIS POINT IT IS NOT INSTANTIATED - it is null !
    if (mUserMarker.isVisible())
        mUserMarker.remove();
    // BELOW THERE IS A PIECE OF CODE THAT SHOULD FIX YOUR ERROR


   //Add new marker
   // ONE MORE COMMENT HERE: that's probably the place where you first set the value to mUserMarker
   // maybe it make sense to check for visibility after this line,
   // don't know if it is your case. just an assumption 
   mUserMarker =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .title("Pickup Here")
           .snippet("")
           .position(new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();
    bRequest.setText("Getting your driver......");
    findDriver();

}
```

Please check comments I left in your piece of code.

To fix NPE in the line I commented try this (basically just check for null):

```
if (mUserMarker != null && mUserMarker.isVisible()) {
    mUserMarker.remove();
}
```

Another option is to instantiate `mUserMarker` before you use it.

Happy hacking :)